# test local sembast .db

Tags: flutter, testing, sembast

I would like to check that values inside sembast db are correct in a unit test.
There is databaseFactoryMemory, but I need to test on the actual .db
It is done in the sembast repo by calling the following path :

```dart
String dbPathFromName(String name) =>
    join('.dart_tool', 'sembast', 'test', name);
```

How could I implement the same thing ?

Comment: For a unit test, the Sembast db will reside on the filesystem of the machine you are testing on, so one solution would be to pass in the directory and filename to use to wherever you perform the `await databaseFactoryIo.openDatabase` call.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply,
Would that work for a test on android ? I fail to grasp how I could do this in the test.
I thought test was executed only locally.

Comment: Unit tests are executed locally on your machine, so you couldn't run it against a Sembast db on your Android device. But, you can do all your Sembast tests locally - create the db,  populate it, perform some queries etc.